# Select value inside div created by clone

Tags: jquery, forms, html, copy, clone

I am using the `.clone()` to create multiple copies of a form and then renaming the id of each copy so that the ids are unique.

I am having trouble accessing the input from the copied forms. I can select the input for the first form, but all subsequent forms return "invalid reference" for each of the input values.

I am accessing the input value with
`$("#" + form_id + " #form_input").val()` which works on the first instance of the form, but not the subsequent.

My form ids are all named correctly and my jquery references are all okay. Is the problem that the copied forms are created on page load? Should I be using `.live()`?

Comment: My apologies. The input id isn't actually called #input, I just put that for demonstration. I have updated my question.

Comment: Also, each form_id is unique.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are using input as an id.  Try changing it to a class.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select `#input` multiple times from under different parents (unless they are all nested).

You may only use an id once per page to point to one element.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see. each of your forms have unique ID's, but it seems that your inputs all have the Id "input".
Which makes the first reference legal but all subsequent ones invalid.